# UICollectionViewCell register class fails, but register nib works

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Creating a custom `UICollectionViewCell` for my `UICollectionViewController`, it works by registering the nib; however, fails to register by class.

**Using registerClass() - fails**

Registering by class seems correct - it builds, but throws an exception at runtime unwrapping optional elements from the UIView.  Without referencing outlets, it runs; however, no cells appear within the collection view.

```
collectionView?.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, 
                              forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Clearly the view is not loaded; however, I'd think setting the custom class of the cell would provide necessary linkage.

**Using registerNib() - works**

Registering by nib works, which makes sense as it is explicitly loading the view.

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView?.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Here the view is explicitly referenced, and custom class is set for the view; however, something about this seems wrong.

## Sample project

Isolating the issue in a sample project, below are views and code to replicate; or, this project is [available at GitHub](https://github.com/jasonsturges/UICollectionView-Test).

**Main.storyboard**

My main storyboard initial view controller is a `UICollectionViewController` subclassed as `MyCollectionViewController`:

[image: UICollectionViewController]

**MyCollectionViewController.swift**

Showing both registering by nib, and by class:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var data = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data = ["a", "b", "c"]

        // This works, by nib
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")

        // This fails, by class
        //collectionView?.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        cell.title.text = data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

**MyCollectionViewCell.xib**

View is a `UICollectionViewCell` subclassed as `MyCollectionViewCell` with a `UILabel`:

[image: MyCollectionViewCell]

In my nib the *Collection Reusable View Identifier* has been set to: `myCell`:

[image: MyCollectionViewCell-identifier]

**MyCollectionViewCell.swift**

Defines the class, and has an `IBOutlet` to the label:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

}
```

Using the nib, execution appears as:

[image: iphone-4s]

Why can't I register `UICollectionViewCell` by class?

As well, I'm a little fuzzy as to whether the prototype cell needs to remain on the main storyboard collection view controller.  There, I have not defined any reusable view identifier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I see this link [Overview Collection View](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_6_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout)

> If the cell class was written in code, the registration is performed using the registerClass: method of UICollectionView. For example:
>   [self.myCollectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MYCELL"];
>   In the event that the cell is contained within an Interface Builder NIB file, the registerNib: method is used instead.

So your collection cell create with nib, you should register with nib. If your cell written totally in code you will need register with class.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you register the class in the storyboard and give it a reuse identifier there, then you shouldn't be registering it's class *or* it's nib in code.

Comment: It's not - I don't want to use the prototype cell as there's no way to subclass it.  This cell only provides size, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It is not collectionview that is failing here. You custom class contains label which is implicitly unwrapped optional defined as this,

```
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
```

And that is the reason for failure. Where do you instantiate it ? And your datasource methods gets called which is like this,

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.title.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

There you are trying to set text to this property **title** which is nil, which crashes your app.

Initialize your label inside collectionView **initWithFrame:** method if you use it in code that should should be fixed.

Add this code to your cell subclass when using in code,

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        contentView.addSubview(title)
        self.title = title

        title.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor).active = true
        title.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.leftAnchor).active = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: `title` is just an outlet to a `UILabel` instantiated by the view, unless I'm missing something, here.  This still would not link the view, though, as `myCell` is defined in the nib.  This fails with: reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier myCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'` - really appreciate this insight, though, thanks.

Comment: It just does not matter if your property has @IBOutlet. It is just some qualifier to let nib know that a view has some connection to property in code.  If you are using code to registerClass then use the code as I did above. Or else if you use nib then your code should work just fine without any modification.

Comment: Where do you register your class not in code ?? Where in nib file or storyboard ?

Comment: Aha - your solution works perfectly.  This provides a code implementation that works using `registerClass`.  Sorry for the confusion - this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

if you define cell from a nib file,system will choose nib file to instantiate the cell. If not define any nib file(totally maintain by code), the cell should be init by the

```
- initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

method.
When you use

```
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

the method `- awakeFromNib` will be called if you use nib to maintain the view;
else

```
- initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

will be called.