# How to use NSCollectionViewItem without subclassing it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I am writing a very simple macOS application that I'd like to show a few images in a collection view. I don't need any special behavior for how they are displayed. The [docs for NSCollectionViewItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewitem) say:

> The default implementation of this class supports the creation of a simple item that displays a single image or string.

That is what I want. However, I can't find any information on how to create a default `NSCollectionViewItem`.

The [documentation for NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionview?language=objc) states:

> Every data source object is required to implement the following methods:
>
> collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:
>
> collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:

The second method above returns an `NSCollectionViewItem`. From reading examples I gather that the traditional way of creating an `NSCollectionViewItem` in this case is to call:

```
NSCollectionViewItem*   newCollectionViewItem   = [imageCollectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:<some identifier>
                                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The problem is that I don't understand what `<some identifier>` should be. I don't have a nib that contains an `NSCollectionViewItem` because I'm not subclassing it or customizing it in any way. I've tried adding the following to my data source:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [imageCollectionView registerClass:[NSCollectionViewItem class]
                 forItemWithIdentifier:@"Image"];
}
```

where `imageCollectionView` is the `NSCollectionView` in question. And then in my `- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` method, I call:

```
NSCollectionViewItem*   newCollectionViewItem   = [imageCollectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"Image"
                                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But this throws an exception and prints this to the console:

> 2016-12-19 17:51:27.463 MyApp[28177:3926764] -[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: NSCollectionViewItem in bundle (null).

followed by a stack trace.

So how do I go about creating and using an `NSCollectionViewItem` that isn't subclassed or modified in any way?

Comment: Here are my thoughts.  No. 1, you should state the version of Xcode you are using.  It appears that you are using Xcode 7 or lower.  There have been changes with the itemForRepresentedObjectAt method since introduction of Xcode 8.  No. 2, identifiier is the name of the NSCollectionViewItem xib file.  So setting 'Image' to the identifier does not make sense.  No. 3, you should just create a collectionitem Xib file except that.  It was terribly difficult when I did it in Swift some 3 to 4 weeks ago since information is limited for Swift.

Comment: 1.) I'm using Xcode 8.2 on macOS 10.11.6. 2) As I mentioned, I don't have an NSCollectionViewItem xib file, so there's no identifier I can give for a .xib file. Also, the docs say you can register a class instead of a .xib file, so that's probably what I'd like to do (and tried to do as you can see above). 3) I don't understand this sentence, so I don't have a response.

Comment: Oops...  I was going to write 'except that it was terribly...'  As far as I know, the makeItemWithIdentifier method has been renamed makeItem since Xcode 8.  But if you say you are using Xcode 8, I guess you are using Xcode 8.  Well, good luck...

Comment: I believe it's the following topic that I used as a reference when I tried to do the same (without using a xib file for collection item) a few years ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660626/how-to-create-nscollectionview-programatically-from-scratch  See if it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, in the answer, they subclass `NSCollectionViewItem` which I am trying to avoid. The docs say you don't have to subclass it, and I'd like not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple example which uses a Nib for the item's prototype:

```
@interface ViewController()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSCollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSNib *theNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"Item" bundle:nil];

    [self.collectionView registerNib:theNib forItemWithIdentifier:@"item"];
}

#pragma mark NSCollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(NSCollectionView *)inCollectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)inCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)inSection {
    return 10;
}

- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)inCollectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)inIndexPath {
    NSCollectionViewItem *theItem = [inCollectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"item" forIndexPath:inIndexPath];
    NSTextField *theLabel = (NSTextField *)theItem.view;

    theLabel.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d", (int)inIndexPath.section, (int)inIndexPath.item];
    return theItem;
}

@end
```

The NIB contains just a `NSCollectionViewItem` with a text field as view.

**Addendum:**
I think you should create a `NSCollectionViewItem.xib` for the registerClass variant. A view controller will search for a NIB with its class name, if you doesn't create its view manually in `loadView`. Thus, you can't use plain `NSCollectionViewItem` without a NIB for registering a class, because of `makeItemWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will access the view of the item.

Comment: But why is a NIB required? Why can't we use `-registerClass:` instead of `-registerNib:`? And why do you need to add a text field as the view? The docs say that the default implementation includes a text field and an image view.

Comment: I've added an addendum.

Comment: @user1118321 please check following link it will solve your confusion about -registerClass: instead of -registerNib:?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396623/uicollectionviewcell-register-class-fails-but-register-nib-works

Comment: I'm not sure what that was supposed to tell me. The accepted answer says "So your collection cell create with nib, you should register with nib. If your cell written totally in code you will need register with class." In my case, it's totally in code - I'm using the default `NSCollectionViewItem`, but registering that class doesn't work.

Comment: If you want register class `NSCollectionViewItem` you **must** include a NIB named `NSCollectionViewItem` in you app, because `NSCollectionViewItem` is a subclass of `NSViewController`, and instances of this class create their views via `loadView`. The default implementation of this method looks for a NIB named like its class name, and that is `NSCollectionViewItem`. Since `makeItemWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`instantiates the view already, you have no chance to assign a view before `loadView`is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's unfortunate that it needs to be that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set up `NSCollectionView` without needing to add a `.xib` file.

The trick was inheriting from `NSCollectionViewItem` and using that subclass for `-[NSCollectionView registerClass:forItemWithIdentifier:]`.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MyViewItem : NSCollectionViewItem
@end

@implementation MyViewItem {
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSNibName)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    
    NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Button"];

    [self setView:button];
    
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    IBOutlet NSCollectionView *_collectionView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[MyViewItem class]
             forItemWithIdentifier:@"item"];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (NSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    return [_collectionView makeItemWithIdentifier:@"item" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

@end
```